# Bash : colored copy / paste

Tags: bash

As everybody, i have a few colorized output in my bash.
I want to keep the colorized syntax when copying an extract to a HTML editor for example.
Is there a way to handle this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

If you are talking about colorized output of some command line utilities like `ls`, `grep`, `cmake`, `git diff`, etc, please note, that it doesn’t have any relations to GNU Bash.

Anyway, there is several tools for converting output colorized with ANSI escape sequences to HTML:

- `aha` from package of the same name
- `ansi2html` from [HTML::FromANSI](http://search.cpan.org/~nuffin/HTML-FromANSI-2.03/lib/HTML/FromANSI.pm) Perl module (not packaged in Ubuntu repo, can be installed from CPAN)
- `ansi2html.sh` by [pixelb](https://github.com/pixelb/scripts/blob/master/scripts/ansi2html.sh) (not packaged, download from git)

Usage of all of them is rather simple: they read terminal escape sequences from `stdin` and put HTML to `stdout`. But note: most of utils don’t colorize output if it is not going to terminal. You have to order them to produce colorized output explicitly. E. g.:

```
$ ls --color=always | aha | xsel -i -b
```

`xsel -i -b` here will copy HTML to clipboard.

Comment: This (`aha`) worked beautifully; thank you very much!

Comment: aha - brilliant!  This is almost perfect for me.  To be able to copy formatted  text, I adapted to route to tmp, open in browser, then just copy/paste as for other sites: `git -c color.ui=always diff | aha > /tmp/diff.html  && firefox /tmp/diff.html`   ...and yes I know the OP wanted the html, but many of us will stumble here wanting the formatting generally.

Answer (score -4):

You need to use javascript libraries for that, you cannot directly copy/paste and keep the colours as they are. Some of the popular libraries for this are:

- [Google's prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)
- [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)
- [Chilli](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)

Source: [Similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647724/color-syntax-highlighting-within-an-html-code-tag)

Comment: That question was not similar at all, and these utilities won't do what the OP wants.